# Check if the sum/product of the digits in even position is devider of number

Tags: c++, function

Write a program that will output all numbers in specific range who can be divided by their sum and product of their even positions. Meanwhile, if there is a 0 on even position, to ignore it. I wrote the program below however it seems to be crashing when ran for some reason. No errors, programs runs fine, then I input the range and it crashes.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int zbirparnicifri(int x);
int proizparnicifri(int x);

int main()
{
    int x, y, br = 0;
    cin >> x >> y;

    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++){
        int proizcif = proizparnicifri(i);
        int zbircif = zbirparnicifri(i);
        if(zbircif != 0 && proizcif != 0){
            if (i % proizcif == 0 && i % zbircif == 0){
                cout << i << endl;
                br++;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int zbirparnicifri(int x)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(x > 0){
        if (x % 100 != 0)
            sum += x % 100;
        x /= 100;
    }
    return sum;
}

int proizparnicifri(int x)
{
    int proiz = 1;
    while(x > 0){
        if (x % 100 != 0)
            proiz *= x % 100;
        x /= 100;
    }
    return proiz;
}
```

Comment: The % operator is division, returns the remainder. You might be dividing by zero.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that fixes the problem, however my solution isn't good enough to check for "even" positions of numbers without using arrays.

Comment: Can you list out the numbers from lets say the range of 0 to 20 that you want your program to list out it might make things a little clearer

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stack overflow. You can't expect the community to debug your program unless you have shown an honest effort to try something yourself.  For example, did you try adding some print/cout statements to discover what line your program was crashing on (and the value of certain variables)?  Did you try stepping through with a debugger.

Since I'm in a good mood, let's see what the debugger says...

```
jselbie@judaspriest ~ $ gdb a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc....
Reading symbols from /home/jselbie/a.out...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jselbie/a.out 
10
20

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x00000000004009f5 in main () at foo.cpp:17
17          if (i % proizcif == 0 && i % zbircif == 0){
(gdb) print i
$1 = 10
(gdb) print proizcif
$2 = 0
(gdb) print zbircif
$3 = 0
```

So there you go - "proizcif" is zero. As well as zbifcif being zero.  So it crashes on line 17 trying to compute "i % 0"

Comment: @user3002211 - The next time your program crashes (or doesn't work), please make an honest effort to debug it yourself.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't really think of such a mistake, but I'll surely check next time before asking. Once again thanks :)